# Не корректно работает код на JQuery

Tags: jquery

[![Больше 575][1]][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXn19.png
У меня контент при ширине экрана меньше 575px сворачивается в спойлер
Если ширина меньше либо равна 575, то весь контент сворачивается в спойлер
[![ширина меньше либо равна 575][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZgij.png
После того, как пользователь нажал на спойлер, посмотрел его контент и закрыл его у меня при переходе на ширину больше 575px то контент не отображается без перезагрузки браузера. Я нашел причину. До нажатия спойлера в консоль браузера нет инлайновых стилей блоков
[![нет инлайновых слитей][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYeBh.png
После того, как пользователь нажал на спойлер, то появляется в консоли display:block, когда пользователь закрывает спойлер, то в консоли на всех ширинах браузера отображается display: none
[![ширинах браузера отображается display: none][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IbZT.png
КАК МНЕ УБРАТЬ ЭТУ ПРОБЛЕМУ
Вот мой код

```
  $('.header-title').click(function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle(300);
    if ($(document).width() > 575){
      $('.header-wrapper').css('display','block');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Такой код рабочий оказался рабочий. Вместо метода метод .slideToggle(300) я применил метод .toggleClass('header-wrapper')

```
  $('.header-title').click(function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().toggleClass('header-wrapper');
  });
```